# Git+Heroku: how to deploy the code from new branch?

Tags: git, heroku, git-branch

On my project on localhost, I created a new branch (let's call it `update1`) and I committed there the new updates. Then I pushed it to Heroku.

When I open the project on Heroku, there are still data from the original (master) branch, not the new ones from `update1`.

How to display the new modifications, which are in the `update1` branch?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code - looks like, from that doc, Heroku will only display the `master` branch.

Comment: thanks, but it does, but as is possible to see, I can put my local branch into Heroku's master branch, what is what I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git push heroku update1:master
```

does the trick.

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps